# How to set cursor position to the top-left edge of input

Tags: html, css

Let I've an input field like the following:

[image]

How can I set cursor postition to the top-left edge of this input field?

Comment: If you intend to use such a large input field with that requirement, the `TextArea` is what you want, not the text field.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This should work

```
input {
   padding-top: 0;
   padding-left: 0;
   line-height: 1em; // this probably doesn't matter
}
```

It seems that you likely have padding of like `40px 0` or something. So the top and bottom has a lot of space (*padding*) on the top and bottom.

EDIT:

If that didn't work, you likely have a `height` set for your input, which is bad. Since an input is intended to only be one line. If you want multiple lines you are to use `<textarea></textarea>` tags instead of `<input>`

If you don't want to use `<textarea>` but have a bigger height for some reason, **remove** the height from your input and just use padding like this

http://jsfiddle.net/PVRp4/

```
input {
    padding: 0 0 400px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Textarea or big size text input ? Input is for single line element use `<textarea></textarea>`. Code pls ...
Remove all whitespace between `<textarea></textarea>` or `<input></input>`tags.

Or in your css code you have text-align: center to your parent elements, or somewhere else but its still formating your input. Press f12 in the browser and check the element.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR there is no option the place the cursor inside of an input field, except left, center, or right. Vertical Alignment isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution for me was within the HTML code for my ASP:TextBox was at the end of my tagline put "...TextMode="MultiLine" /> as below:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtPermissionSearch" runat="server" Width="150px" Height ="150px" TextMode="MultiLine" />
```