# How to create a memo text in a web page? (Multiline and starting at top)

Tags: html, kendo-ui

I have an input-text in my page (Kendo).

And I want to do some points:

- The text has to start left to right.
- The text has to start on top.
- The text is a memo it has to be a multiline text.

How do you do that?

```
        <div>
            <input type="text" class="k-input text-box" id="someMemoText"
                   style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top; text-wrap: normal; width: 400px; height: 96px;"
                   multiple="multiple" />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[How to set cursor position to the top-left edge of input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22166443/how-to-set-cursor-position-to-the-top-left-edge-of-input/22166489)

Changing input into textarea is the solution that works for me.